# How to initiate animation after other (hovered) animation finished?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, chaining

I am struggling with two animations. What I would like to happen is that by hovering one animation, that animation starts and once that one is finished, the other animation starts (without having to hover the second animation). How can I accomplish this? I am completely lost. Do I need to use Javascript? (I am still a newbie)

So I would like that .link link--manko starts first and then #blendlogo.

my css part

```
#blendlogo{
-webkit-animation-name: wiggle;
-ms-animation-name: wiggle;
-ms-animation-duration: 750ms;
-webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.link link--manko:hover {
-webkit-animation-name: wiggle;
-ms-animation-name: wiggle;
-ms-animation-duration: 750ms;
-webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

}

```
#webkit-keyframes wiggle {
0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);}
25% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);}
50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);}
75% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
```

}

```
@-ms-keyframes wiggle {
0% {-ms-transform: rotate(1deg);}
25% {-ms-transform: rotate(-1deg);}
50% {-ms-transform: rotate(1.5deg);}
75% {-ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);}
100% {-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
```

}

```
@keyframes wiggle {
0% {transform: rotate(10deg);}
25% {transform: rotate(-10deg);}
50% {transform: rotate(20deg);}
75% {transform: rotate(-5deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
```

}

Comment: Hi there! Could you add your current code? This way we can help you with your existing code.

Comment: You may want to check out https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: A simple solution could be to use `transition-delay` on the element you want to animate after the first animation has ended. But it's hard to tell without a snippet of your code.

Comment: I added my code :)

Comment: You also need to include your HTML.